# How can I sort the attributes of an object in Java

Tags: java, object, objectmapper, mapper

Do you know why when debbuging my app the order of the attributes of my address object is changed? I need to check it the address stored in the database is equal to the one coming from the frontend. I'm using objectmapper to get the object into text so the I can compare 2 strings but due this situation I always get false as the order change as you can see in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: I'd say parse the json string and then compare actual objects, not their string representation. Implying, of course, that `Address` should have an appropriate `equals` method.

Comment: Hello Fede, how I do that? Thanks

Comment: You should not be comparing JSON as strings, as the order of the attributes is not meaningful. Either compare JsonObjects, or use a library like JsonUnit or Hamcrest JsonMatchers to compare in an order-independent manner.

Comment: In JSON everything in an array [] is in order, everything in {} is not guaranteed to be in order ({} is a map).

Answer (score 1):

Using new `ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString()` should give you the fields in order as you expect it to.
As @Federico klez Culloca stated, you should instead use the objects themselves to compare.
You should construct an `Address` object from `address.getAddressString()` or just directly compare `address` to `a` using `a.equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse strings to `JsonNode` and compare them. Jackson provides overrides of `equals(Object o)` for all node types.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode actualNode = mapper.readTree(actualJson);
JsonNode expectedNode = mapper.readTree(expectedJson));
boolean matches = actualNode.equals(expectedNode);
```

[This guide](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-compare-two-json-objects) should be helpful as well.

The other option is to provide implementation of `equals()` in you custom class, as mentioned in comments.